# PuppeteerCrawler Caching of requests already Scraped (urls seen by the scraper )

Tags: node.js, web-scraping, puppeteer

I am using the apify SDK to write a node js crawler, is there an npm package I can use to cache requests to avoid recrawling URLs. (something that works like the python's [scrapy-deltafetch](https://pypi.org/project/scrapy-deltafetch/) )